# Removing the spacing from the output

Tags: php

I have this code and it works absolutely fine when I do executions of the inputs individually but when you add the inputs in a loop, theres this extra spacing gets added between the last word. I cant find where that is coming from.

here is the code:

```
function new($term)
{

    $exp = explode(" ", $term);

    sort($exp);

    foreach($exp as $val)
    {
        echo $val;
    }

}
```

This basically converts `"k duz q rc lvraw"`, into `"duzklvrawqrc"` only when you write `new("k duz q rc lvraw")`

but if I have `$a = array("k duz q rc lvraw", "mybea zdr yubx xe dyroiy");`
and with the code

```
foreach($a as $test)
{

new($test);
echo "\n";

}
```

The output comes out to be

```
"duzklvraw
qrc"
```

and

```
"dyroiy
mybeaxeyubxzdr"
```

This extra `"\n"` gets added, before the last few characters and at the end of the sentence and when you try to copy/paste it.. the lines are not consistent.

Why is this happening... this is the exact code!

Answer (score 1):

"new" is a PHP keyword used for creating objects. Try using a different function name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This code shouldn't even run, since `new` is a keyword in PHP and cannot be used as a function name. However, if I rename `new` to something else, it works fine; see [this example on codepad](http://codepad.org/pGiim8Cv).